# How does an air bubble have 2 surfaces and a liquid drop has 1 surface?

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

My teacher told me that an air bubble has 2 surfaces and a liquid drop has only 1 which is the reason for the air bubble having twice the pressure difference as a liquid drop with same surface tension. But I couldn't get it how an air bubble has 2 surfaces isn't it just 1 spherical surface ? Please help

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Commenters, please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: Are you thinking of an air bubble _in water_, or a bubble _in air_?  (The former would have only one surface, the latter two.)

Comment: I was thinking about a bubble in air

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Think about what a microscopic observer would experience as they moved from somewhere outside the bubble to its centre.

With an air bubble they go from air (outside) to water (the "shell" of the bubble) to air again (centre). So they pass through two surfaces.

With a water drop they go from air (outside) to water (all the way from the surface of the drop to its centre). So they only pass through one surface.

Comment: This doesn't explain the "*twice the pressure difference*" claim.

Answer (score 17):

I think there is a little confusion here between a bubble and a membrane.

What is referred here as an air bubble, is actually a membrane of liquid form enclosing a volume of gas, and floating inside another volume of gas (usually air).

And what people refer to as air bubbles, is this membrane, which like any other membrane has two surfaces, while a pure air bubble inside any liquid has only one surface.

Answer (score 6):

A air bubble is hollow inside it.
It doesn't pop or pops just due to pressure difference inside it and outside it.
Hence it has 2 surfaces- the inside one and outside one

While water drop has only one surface i.e the outside one

Comment: then why does a water drop pop ?

Comment: Who said a water drop pops? It doesn't pop . Its just a shape of water

Comment: A water drop can break due to stresses on it (like its own weight, and air resistance) overcoming its surface tension. A bubble is lighter, so it doesn't fall much against air resistance, and its insides don't have any more weight than the air outside.

Answer (score 2):

Think bubble as a bag.
A bubble is an empty bag. The bubble has an inside and outside.
The drop is a bag full filled with the same material of the membrane.

Answer (score 0):

This video will surely help

https://youtu.be/Us7sk1OrcUc
**Watch at high speed( at least 1.5x)**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/401512)

Answer (score 0):

If a bubble has same inner an putter environment like an air bubble or soap bubble then it has 2 surfaces
If the bubble has two different environment on the inner and outer side like water drop in air or air bubble in water then it has 1 surface